# comparison between char* values

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, char, comparison

I am learning c programming at school, and having a question about char*.
I initialized char* str5 and char* str6, and their values are the exact same.
what I want to confirm is that if I compare them in if statement, is it always comparing its addresses? If so, Why?

```
char* str5 = "hold";
  printf("str5: %s\n", str5, str5);


  char* str6 = "hold";

  if (str5 == str6){
    printf("str5 and str6 point to the same address\n");
  }  
  else{
    printf("str5 and str6 point to different addresses\n");

  }
```

I appreciate any feedback, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, the code is comparing the addresses of the two strings, not the content of the strings.  The problem is that the two addresses might be the same, or they might be different. So the `if` statement gives you no useful information. On some systems the code will always print "same". Other systems will always print "different". And still other systems may print either "same" or "different" depending on compiler settings and/or the phase of the moon.

Comment: The two pointers are local variables, so......they are umm.....compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings aren't a built-in type in C.  What you have are two variables of type `char *`, each of which contains the address of the first character of a string constant.

So when you compare `str5` with `str6` using `==`, you're comparing two addresses.

If you want to compare two strings for equality, you need to use the `strcmp` function.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation! I appreciate it